# Calculating angular velocity with known rotation matrix and translation

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, lie-algebra, angular-velocity

I have an available rotation matrix between two points, as well as a translation but how to calculate angular velocity in the body frame?
I know how to calculate angular velocity when there is no translation (just derivative) but how to calculate when there is translation.

Can someone provide some insight into how I can compute this?

Comment: Please include the work you've already done to solve this problem so people posting an answer have a point to start from.

Comment: subtract translation of a point and you get pure rotation about that point. You can always write the motion of a rigid body as a composition of translation and rotation

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I understand the aforementioned but I am currently stuck at the part where I know my rotation matrix from points and the time difference between them but can't find mathematical equations for discrete equations for evaluating angles from the rotation matrix (I read that euler equations are not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take the rotation matrix ${\rm R}$ and extract the axis $\boldsymbol{k}$ and angle $\theta$.

$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{ {\rm tr}({\rm R})-1}{2} \right) $$

$$ \boldsymbol{k} = \frac{1}{2 \sin \theta} \pmatrix{ {\rm R}_{32} - {\rm R}_{23} \\ {\rm R}_{13}-{\rm R}_{31} \\ {\rm R}_{21}-{\rm R}_{12} } $$

<sub>Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_rotation_matrix_to_axis%E2%80%93angle</sub>

If the rotation happens in known time span $\Delta t$ then the average rotational speed is $\omega = \tfrac{\theta}{\Delta t}$ and the average rotational velocity vector

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega} = \tfrac{\theta}{\Delta t} \boldsymbol{k} $$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I agree, but how to get these angles, can they be Euler angles?  I suppose that this problem has to be solved within S03, but I can't find any suitable equations for nontrivial rotation matrix with a discrete time interval

Comment: @aguero - take for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Log_map_from_SO(3)_to_%F0%9D%94%B0%F0%9D%94%AC(3) which shows how to extract axis angle from rotation matrix.